# Select from Select MSSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

```
select count (*) 
  from 
  
  (SELECT  
count (c.ID_CENTRAL)
FROM dbCENTRAL c
LEFT JOIN GRUPO_CLIENTE GRUPO ON GRUPO.CD_GRUPO_CLIENTE = C.CD_GRUPO_CLIENTE
WHERE 1=1
AND C.FG_ATIVO = 1
AND C.CTRL_CENTRAL = 1  
GROUP BY C.ID_CENTRAL,GRUPO.NM_DESCRICAO) as r
```

Bem no código acima estou tentando contar quantos ids de clientes eu tenho ativo, porem, por algumas particularidades do sistema, preciso usar o grupo by para trazer o resultado correto

Pensei em utilizar a forma que esta no código, porem o SSMS acusa que tem um erro na consulta e não consegui achar o que pode ser este erro. Se não estiver correta qual o jeito certo para fazer? Obrigado =)

[Print Screen do Codigo com o Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUgjf.png)

Comment: Parece provável que seja possível algo diferente nessa consulta, mas especificamente sobre o erro (acho que faltou postar a mensagem de erro) experimente adicionar aliases para os 2 Count

Comment: Ola Imex, realmente esqueci a print do erro, vou tentar colocar os Aliases e ver se da certo, ai posto o erro tbm =).. obrigado

Comment: Imex, obrigado cara, realmente era so os ALIES, obrigado de verdade...

Answer (score 0):

Veja se dessa formas resolve, vc vai ter a qtde por Central;

SELECT C.CTRL_CENTRAL, count(c.ID_CENTRAL) AS QTDE
FROM dbCENTRAL c
LEFT JOIN GRUPO_CLIENTE GRUPO ON GRUPO.CD_GRUPO_CLIENTE = C.CD_GRUPO_CLIENTE
WHERE C.FG_ATIVO = 1
GROUP BY C.CTRL_CENTRAL

Comment: W.V, não deu certo....não trouxe a informação que eu precisava ainda, mas a info que trouxe vai me ajudar em outro lugar kkkkkkk...

Comment: Que bom, que ajudou!!! top